# yahoo api timezone

Tags: yahoo-finance

how can i receive a specific time zone for the received date-time from yahoo api?

and what is the default time zone?

http://hk.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?e=.csv&f=sl1d1t1&s=USDHKD=x

http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?e=.csv&f=sl1d1t1&s=USDHKD=x

the received time is the same

```
private String GetRequest() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException{
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?e=.csv&f=sl1d1t1&s=USDHKD=x");
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(
          response.getEntity().getContent()
        )
      );

    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
         String[] RowData = line.split(",");
         String value = RowData[1];//value = qoute
         String date = RowData[2].replaceAll("\"", "");
         String time = RowData[3].replaceAll("\"", "");
         tvDateTimeValue.setText(date+"\t"+time);
         return value;
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: To me it rather seems that the date/time is given in EST/EDT. Did I miss something? I am using the exact same format specifier as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the value is *always* given in UTC. That seems entirely reasonable to me. In particular, it's never ambiguous, and never subject to historical changes etc.

If you want to display the data in a particular time zone, perform the translation yourself. (I'd give sample code, but you haven't specified how you're accessing the API, e.g. which language you're using.)

Answer (score 4):

Looks like it is `America/New_York` time zone.

These guys think so too (though not sure what is their source of information)

http://www.kksou.com/php-gtk2/Joomla-Gadgets/Yahoo-Stock-Quote-AJAX-version.php